# Unit Testing AWS python lambda global variable patch doesnt work

Tags: python

I am trying to unit test Python based aws lambda code. I tried to use patch to mock environment variables but it throws error.How to handle global variables during unit testing. Any help is appreciated

Tried @mock @patch but nothing seems to be working. When executing the testcase the values seems to be empty

[registration.py]

```py
    import os 

    #Global Variables
    DEBUG = os.environ.get("EnableLog")
    rest_endpoint = os.environ.get('restApiEndpoint')
    db_fn_endpoint = rest_endpoint+":3000/rpc/"

    def lambda_handler(event,context):
    return "success" #to see if this works

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        lambda_handler('', '')
```

Unit Test [test_registration.py]

```py
    import json
    import pytest
    import sys, os
    from mock import patch
    from businesslogic import registration

    @mock.patch.dict(os.environ,{'EnableLog':'True'})
    @mock.patch.dict(os.environ,{'restApiEndpoint':'http://localhost'})

    @patch('registration.restApiEndpoint', 'http://localhost') 


    def test_lambda_handler():
       assert lambda_handler() =="success"
```

When I run pytest test_registration.py

I get below exception

```
businesslogic\registration.py:6: in <module>
    db_fn_endpoint = rest_endpoint+":3000/rpc/"
E   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Comment: Have you verified that `restApiEndpoint` is an environment variable for the lambda function and that it has a value?

Comment: @Alex yes. restApiEndpoint is an env variable and has a valid value. Only when I try to unit test the lambda code it fails to patch the value for it.

Comment: You might consider using [`pytest-env`](https://github.com/MobileDynasty/pytest-env) plugin

Comment: Thank you for pointer. Will try and update the results

Comment: @Alex finally got it working. Didnt try with py-env but made following changes 

instead of 
`DEBUG = os.environ.get("EnableLog")`

 used
 `DEBUG = os.getenv("EnableLog")`
  
 and used monkey patch in unit test instead of patch

  `@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
   def env_setup(monkeypatch):
    print("Called")
    monkeypatch.setenv("DEBUG","True")`

 Thank you for helping

Answer (score -2):

You can pass it as `restApiEndpoint=http://localhost python -m pytest`
OR
you if you are using sh file to run export before running test 
`export restApiEndpoint=http://localhost`